# How to get byte[] from a file in vertx

Tags: java, arrays, file-upload, byte, vert.x

I am trying to extract byte[] from a file which I will receive in form-data in a post call. However, i didn't find any useful code snippet that can help me to get the byte[]. Below is the code that i am trying

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
        Vertx vertx =Vertx.vertx();
        HttpServer httpServer= vertx.createHttpServer() ;

        Router router=Router.router(vertx);
router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create().setUploadsDirectory("uploads"));

 router.post("/form").handler(ctx -> {
           ctx.response().putHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");

            ctx.response().setChunked(true);
            MultiMap attributes = ctx.request().formAttributes();
            Set<io.vertx.ext.web.FileUpload> uploads = ctx.fileUploads();
            ctx.response().end();
      }

  httpServer
     .requestHandler(router::accept)
     .listen(8091);
    }
```

Here the file is getting uploaded on the server in uploads folder. However, i don't want to upload the file on servers, instead i want the byte[] of the file to transfer to different service for uploading. So if i comment this line
router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create().setUploadsDirectory("uploads"));
file is not uploaded to system. So now can someone tell me how to get byte[] of the file if i am not uploading the file on server.

Answer (score 3):

The `FileUpload` object gives you the path of the uploaded file. You can use Vert.x `FileSystem` API to load its content:

```
vertx.fileSystem().readFile(fileUpload.uploadedFileName(), ar -> {
  if (ar.succeeded()) {
    byte[] content = ar.result().getBytes();
    // use the content
  } else {
    // deal with failure
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, I don't want to upload the file on server rather I want to pass the file bytes[] to a seperate service. So if you can let me a way to get bytes without uploading it on server, then that will be great!!

Comment: So what you want is actually client-side code to load the content before sending?